MathTime Pro 2 Complete
Does anyone know where to get MathTime Pro 2 Complete (got Lite installed already, looking for Complete)
PCTex shop seems to be a dead Yahoo site, not functioning at all.
Thanks in advance!

If I have correct information, the MathTime Pro 2 fonts are 8bit fonts, no Unicode fonts. It is very old project. Using non-Unicode fonts isn't good idea in today's point of view.

The author of those fonts died four years ago unfortunately, so it may be impossible to acquire a (legal) copy of them.

Can you suggest fonts with the same typesetting quality as MathTime Pro 2, but "modern" in your sense?

Stix Two supports Unicode and is another Times lookalike, so that would probably be your best choice. The font is professionally made, and it has probably the largest number of math glyphs available out of any font.

Meh... by far, not the same look and feel. Thanks anyways!

@MaxChernoff NewCM has more glyphs than Stix2.

There have been discussions on converting them into an OpenType math font, but I'm not sure if the project really got started.
